# Connection String Conversion for Deployment on IIS

Tags: c#, database, wcf, iis, visual-studio-2013

I am new to WCF and I have created a wcf service and a Database to write to by using LINQ. In my web.config file it is still using the standard connection string (I don't really understand the content of the connection string)

connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\jarvis.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

that is automatically generated when creating a database. My WCF Interface has the following Operation Contract:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Add", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string Add();
```

When I run the WCF on the local machine with `"http://localhost:58632/WCFService.svc/Add"`, I write to the DB perfectly with no Problem.(Could be because the connection string is meant for local connection)

When I attempt to deploy the application on a server with IP `10.0.0.14` and run `http://10.0.0.14/Service/WCFService/Add` it does not allow me to write to the DB. I think this is because of the connection string, but I am not sure.

The Procedure that I follow to deploy on IIS is"

```
1. Right click on the solution and select Publish...
2. Select Connection and the publish Method is Web Deploy Package
3. I go to the Package location and go in to the zip file to get the content.
4. Place the content in the wwwroot/Service folder, then I attempt to write.
```

How would I go about changing the Connection string so that I can write to the DB when the WCF is deployed on IIS and must SQL Server be installed on the server running the WCF? I don't want to make use of external libraries or applications like `SlowCheetah`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a config transform for the deployment?

A typical project will have a `web.config` file at the root with `web.Debug.config` and `web.Release.config` files underneath that.

You could use those transform files to alter the connection string when you deploy.
EDIT: if you deploy using the "Release" build configuration, then the web.Release.config transform will be used, etc. Also, only define transforms for configuration items that need to be changed when deployed. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The connection string "Data Source" attribute will need to be updated to point to wherever you have the database running. If it's another server, then put that server host name there. If it's supposed to be running on the same server as the WCF service, then you would need SQL installed on that server.

Comment: I have SQL Server installed on the server. The data source that must point to the new location, must the data source then change to `./SQLExpres`?

Comment: if you installed SQL Express with the defaults, then yes, the instance should be accessible at `./SQLExpress`. So the connection string should look something like this: `Data Source=./SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=jarvis;Integrated Security=true;`

Comment: and if I use SQL Server?

Comment: are you able to connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio on the server? If so, just use that same instance name in your connection string.